# How can I remove certain part in each slice of a Nifti image using Python?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, unsupervised-learning, nifti, nibabel

I have a Nifti image (not labeled) with shape (512, 512, 299)
I want to perform Unsupervised segmentation on this 3D image.
However, the image contains bed area which are creating trouble for my clusters.
I have tried clustering and the result is a clustered image with shape **(512, 512)**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: With this amount of information, my guess would be that the problem is not necessarily the 'bed area' but the fact that your segmentation method expects, and produces, 2D images.

Comment: Yes @alle_meije, you are correct, but that was not my focus here. Instead of using software like 3Dslicer to crop the bed area from my 3D image, I wanted to code it out. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

# Load the Nifti image
nifti_file = 'your_image.nii.gz'
img = nib.load(nifti_file)
data = img.get_fdata()

# Define a function to remove the bed area from a single 2D slice
def remove_bed_area(slice_data):
    # Implement your logic here to remove the bed area
    # You might use thresholding, segmentation, or other techniques

    # For example, you can threshold the slice to remove dark areas
    threshold = 100  # Adjust this threshold as needed
    slice_data[slice_data < threshold] = 0

    return slice_data

# Process each slice in the 3D image
for slice_idx in range(data.shape[2]):
    data[:, :, slice_idx] = remove_bed_area(data[:, :, slice_idx])

# Create a new Nifti image with the modified data
modified_img = nib.Nifti1Image(data, img.affine)

# Save the modified Nifti image to a new file
modified_file = 'modified_image.nii.gz'
nib.save(modified_img, modified_file)
```

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't work as the values of my main image and the bed are same and when threshold set to 150 removes the bed area, it also remove some part of my main image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
import nibabel as nib;
img = nib.load ( "withbed.nii.gz" );
data = img.get_fdata();

removed_bed_area = data [ :200, 4:111, : ];
removed_bed_img  = nib.Nifti1Image( removed_bed_area, img.affine );
nib.save( removed_bed_img, "removed_bed.nii.gz" );
```

Mind that this is essentially the same answer as @BradleyDuncanJunior's (and the regions in my example are almost certainly incorrect, so I gave his answer an upvote.